# R: Creating a Table of Factor Levels

Tags: r, categories, data-manipulation, factors

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data:

```
var1 <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
var2 <- c("B1", "B2" )

var_1_a <- as.factor(sample(var1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.3, 0.4)))

var_1_b <- as.factor(sample(var2, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))

my_data = data.frame(var_1_a, var_1_b)

head(my_data)

  var_1_a var_1_b
1      A2      B1
2      A2      B2
3      A1      B2
4      A2      B2
5      A2      B2
6      A3      B1
```

I am trying to create a new data set that summarizes the old data set, something like this:

```
new_data = data.frame(var_1_a = table(my_data$var_1_a ), var_2_a = table(my_data$var_1_b ) )
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(var_1_a = table(my_data$var_1_a), var_2_a = table(my_data$var_1_b)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you'd like the output to look like?  The first table has 3 rows (because there are 3 unique values of the first variable), the second has 2 rows, so you can't append them side-by-side (which is what `data.frame` wants to do)

Comment: I am trying to create something like summary(my_data) . Two rows, two columns : each row containing the frequency of factor levels for the corresponding variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a list instead of a data frame that will allow for different number of rows.

```
new_data = list(var_1_a = data.frame(table(my_data$var_1_a )), var_2_a = data.frame(table(my_data$var_1_b)))
```